# NULL safe object checking in JAVA 8 using ifPresent

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, functional-programming

I have this function:

```
public static long toEpochMilli(OffsetDateTime dateTime) {
    return dateTime.toInstant().toEpochMilli();
}
```

that I want to use but I have to check before if it is null

```
private Long buildBookingValidDate (TimeIntervalType validFor) {

        return Optional.ofNullable(validFor.getStartTimeStamp())
                .ifPresent(DateUtils::toEpochMilli);

    }
```

but I don't know how to return the value

Comment: decide first what do you want to `return` from this method, when the input value is `null`.

Comment: 1. Do not use NULL if possible (and in 99.9999% of the cases it is). 2. Do not misuse the optional type.  Use plain old IF instead

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/OptionalLong.html consider OptionalLong as a return type instead

Comment: The general answer is _not_ to check it; it doesn't seem like the responsibility of this method. Allowing an NPE to escape here seems perfectly reasonable, because whoever is managing the booking should be doing the validity check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how it would look in "normal" Java. Just for comparison.

```
private Long buildBookingValidDate (TimeIntervalType validFor) {
    if(validFor.getStartTimeStamp() == null)
        return null;

    return DateUtils.toEpochMilli(validFor.getStartTimeStamp());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend using `.map` and return `Optional<Long>` instead of `null` when input is `null`.

example using [jshell](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/jshell/introduction-jshell.htm#JSHEL-GUID-630F27C8-1195-4989-9F6B-2C51D46F52C8),

**When input is some value,**

```
jshell> import java.time.OffsetDateTime

jshell> Optional<OffsetDateTime> data = Optional.ofNullable(OffsetDateTime.now())
data ==> Optional[2019-09-08T23:36:48.470738-07:00]

jshell> data.map($ -> $.toInstant().toEpochMilli())
$2 ==> Optional[1568011008470]
```

**When input is empty,** it will return `Optional.empty` but client has to check if the output has value in it

```
jshell> Optional<OffsetDateTime> data = Optional.ofNullable(null)
data ==> Optional.empty

jshell> data.map($ -> $.toInstant().toEpochMilli())
$4 ==> Optional.empty
```

Answer (score 0):

You are misusing `Optional` - it wasn't designed to replace null check.

If you still don't want to use plain, old Java for your case then you can create a helper method like

```
static <T, R> R applyIfNotNull(T obj, Function<T, R> function) {
    return obj != null ? function.apply(obj) : null;
}
```

and call it as follows

```
long time = applyIfNotNull(validFor.getStartTimeStamp(), FooBar::toEpochMilli);
```

and since you like so much `Optional`, you can use it in `applyIfNotNull` method:

```
static <T, R> Optional<R> applyIfNotNull(T obj, Function<T, R> function) {
    return obj != null ? Optional.of(function.apply(obj)) : Optional.empty();
}
```